# Setup Jekyll via Docker?

Tags: docker, jekyll

I am currently trying to setup Jekyll locally via Docker. I found the [official image](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md) which says in it's README:

```
export JEKYLL_VERSION=3.8
docker run --rm \
  --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" \
  -it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION \
  jekyll build
```

Now when I created a folder Jekyll-Test and run the command in the console. The output is:

```
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Configuration file: none
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.018 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

My question is, what's next? The folder is still empty. Is Jekyll even running? I couldn't really figure out how to open it in the browser.

Comment: SO isn't a great place to ask about simply trying to run others' prebuilt Docker images.  I'd suggest contacting the image's maintainer, or one of the other paths at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/community/#where-to-get-support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a Jekyll site, there are at least three steps involved.

1. Create the Jekyll configuration or use a pre-configured template.
2. Build this site
3. Serve the pages

In your attempt, you have performed only the second step (where there was nothing to be built)

**Step 1**: Download and extract a pre-configured site from this URL: https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now

**Step 2**: Build the site using **jekyll build**

If the site was extracted to C:/jekyll-now-master, use the following command to use the Jekyll container to do the build for you.

```
docker run --rm -v "C:/jekyll-now-master:/srv/jekyll" -it jekyll/jekyll:3.8 jekyll build
```

Output:

```
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux-musl] Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
       Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.59 seconds.  Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

The output of the build process is located in a new folder called **C:/jekyll-now-master/_site** .

**Step 3**: Serve the pages (which are in _site folder) using **jekyll serve**

```
docker run --rm -v "C:/jekyll-now-master:/srv/jekyll" -it -p 4000:4000 jekyll/jekyll:3.8 jekyll serve
```

Output:

```
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
       Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.36 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/srv/jekyll'
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Notice that we need to use -p to map the internal 4000 port to be accessible from a browser.
You can access the Jekyll site at http://localhost:4000

The pages will be served as long as the container is running.